# Coding Problem IndexError: list index out of range site

Tags: web-scraping

This is the code line, not sure whats wrong

```
links = []

for json_request in json_links:
    json_receive = requests.get(json_request)
    json_dict = json.loads(json_receive.content) 
    links.append('https://sherloc.unodc.org/cld' + json_dict['results'][0]['uri'])
```

What it's saying

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-207-50fc11b55295> in <module>()
      4     json_receive = requests.get(json_request)
      5     json_dict = json.loads(json_receive.content)
----> 6     links.append('https://sherloc.unodc.org/cld' + json_dict['results'][0]['uri'])

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is in `json_dict['results'][0]['uri']`
try to `console.log(json_dict['results'])`, I guess you will see a null or empty which lead to list index out of range.